# Google colab private cells. Teacher-student mode

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a google colab notebook accesible via shared link (view only). I want some of the cells to make private (completely hidden) until I make them public again.

It's useful when you want students to *think* a little before providing the answer right away. My notebooks are split is sections:

- problem description (public)
- your solution - implement a function, etc. (public)
- my reference solution (should be private until I change it)

It's *not* "Hide the cell" feature because everyone can unhide it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to accomplish what you are trying to do without separate notebooks. All of the notebook contents are in the JSON, so intrepid students could just download the file and observe the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You may make a solution.py in your google drive.

Then write code to read it and print it, using pydrive with file_id.
The code will work only when you share solution.py with students or share it publicly.